# where condition is not working correctly when value is false for varchar column in mysql - Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

In database I have some cars with status and mandatory code, data type for code is varchar(50) and not null.

In the code snippet below,

```
    $car = Car::find()->where(['!=', 'status', Car::STATUS_DELETED])
               ->andWhere(['=', 'code',$userCode])->one();
```

**$userCode** variable come from user interface and always is string code but rarely users input not valid value and before run this code,$userCode value convert to **(bool)false**, in this case final query result in the Yii debugger window is

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE (`status` != 2) AND (`code` = FALSE)
```

and the output line of the database look like the **andWhere** part has been removed

Note that all rows in my table have a valid value for the code field, and I expect in this case to have no record in output.

Could you explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

comparison is done at database level. In database the datatype for code is varchar(50). So, the comparison `code` = FALSE will not work.

If the code column has FALSE value then you need to compare as string.

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE (`status` != 2) AND (`code` = 'FALSE')
```

What do you mean by "I expect in this case to have no record in output."

Comment: By the way, I want to know why Mysql works like this, you are right that the value must be in 'FALSE' for the condition to be checked correctly, but my question is why it actually skips when the input type is not the same as the data field type.

Comment: My expectation was that when a bool data type is given to it, it will probably consider it equal to NULL or an empty string, and since there is no such value in my table for the field, the condition result should not be true so the rest of the conditions are violated because of the AND operator

Comment: @Vajihehhabibi your expectation was wrong. In MySQL the `TRUE` and `FALSE` are constants for `1` and `0` respectively.  If you compare string to number the string is converted to number. When that happens if the string doesn't start with number it's converted to `0`.  So condition like this `'some string' = FALSE` will be true in MySQL.